# How to mount a local directory in a linux server as a disk and allocate specific memory for that disk?

Tags: linux, mount

I installed ubuntu 12.04 in my server.

And I make the folder called 'data001' in the root.

However, I cannot find out data001 through the command 'df'.

I think that I need to mount 'data001' folder as a disk.

Could you let me know how to mount a local directory as a disk and allocate specific memory for that disk?

Finally, I want to approach 'data001' folder through the remote jenkins server.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am really not sure why you think you need to do this or if mounting a local file as a filesystem is in fact the best solution to your problem, but here's one way to do it on Linux (as the root user):

```
# create a file to hold the filesystem as /path/to/local/file
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/local/file bs=1048576 count=<size in MB>

# create a filesystem in the file, where <filesystem> is, for example, 'ext4'
# will prompt asking if it should proceed using a local file
# answer: y
mkfs -t <filesystem> /path/to/local/file

# mount the local file on the target directory
mount /path/to/local/file /path/to/target/directory
```

The mount will be lost at reboot unless you configure `/etc/fstab` accordingly.